# Unable to install net-keepalive module on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: node.js, node-modules, npm-install

I'm able to install net-keepalive module on my MAC OS, but doesn't know why I can't install in on my Ubuntu 16.04. 
The reason that I want to use this module is node.JS net module close event didn't work as my expected, A TCP server unplug Etghernet cable take up to a while to execute to close event. What I want is my Node server able to tell whenever the TCP server Ethernet cable unplug or power off. If net-keepalive module is unable to install on Ubuntu, any other suggestion I will be more than happy to hear.

The error message show as following:

```
chroma@chromaUnity:~$ sudo npm install net-keepalive
[sudo] password for chroma: 

> ref@1.3.2 install /home/chroma/node_modules/net-keepalive/node_modules  /ref
> node-gyp rebuild

/bin/sh: 1: node: not found
gyp: Call to 'node -e "require('nan')"' returned exit status 127 while in binding.    
gyp. while trying to load binding.gyp
gyp ERR! configure error 
gyp ERR! stack Error: `gyp` failed with exit code: 1
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onCpExit (/usr/share/node-gyp/lib         
/configure.js:354:16)
gyp ERR! stack     at emitTwo (events.js:87:13)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:172:7)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:200:12)
gyp ERR! System Linux 4.4.0-31-generic
gyp ERR! command "/usr/bin/nodejs" "/usr/bin/node-gyp" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd /home/chroma/node_modules/net-keepalive/node_modules/ref
gyp ERR! node -v v4.2.6
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.0.3
gyp ERR! not ok 
/home/chroma
├─┬ body-parser@1.15.2 
│ └─┬ debug@2.2.0 
│   └── ms@0.7.1 
└── express@4.14.0 

npm WARN enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/home/chroma/package.json'
npm WARN chroma No description
npm WARN chroma No repository field.
npm WARN chroma No README data
npm WARN chroma No license field.
npm ERR! Linux 4.4.0-31-generic
npm ERR! argv "/usr/bin/nodejs" "/usr/bin/npm" "install" "net-keepalive"
npm ERR! node v4.2.6
npm ERR! npm  v3.5.2
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE

npm ERR! ref@1.3.2 install: `node-gyp rebuild`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the ref@1.3.2 install script 'node-gyp rebuild'.
npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the ref package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     node-gyp rebuild
npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
npm ERR!     npm bugs ref
npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls ref
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /home/chroma/npm-debug.log
```

Comment: Did you also `sudo apt-get install nodejs-legacy`? It looks like you're missing the `node` symlink.

Comment: Hi mscdex, thank you so much. It worked. It my first Ubuntu machine, doesn't realize it require to symlink, can you repost your comment as answer? I mark as answer for it. Thx~~~

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On Ubuntu/Debian if you install node.js via the package manager from the normal distro repositories you will also want to install the `nodejs-legacy` package which will add the commonly used `node` executable symlink (instead of just having the `nodejs` executable).